# mongoTemplate executeCommand error : not authorized

Tags: java, mongodb, mongotemplate

I'm trying to run JS code for MongoDB like this :

```java
String mongoSql = "db.knowledge_resource_copy1.find({_id:ObjectId(\"61517de29946587296c7c375\")}, ).forEach(function(item){
    db.knowledge_resource_copy1.update({_id:item._id}, {$set:{description:item.description.substr(0,5)+\"h3\"}} )
});";
BasicDBObject bson = new BasicDBObject();
bson.put("$eval", mongoSql);
MongoUtils.MONGO_TEMPLATE.executeCommand(bson.toJson());
```

But I got this error :

```
com.mongodb.MongoCommandException: Command failed with error 13 (Unauthorized): 'not authorized.
```

How to solve this?

Comment: Can you print `bson.toJson()` result and add it to your question by [edit] it ?

Comment: mongoSql like this: db.knowledge_resource_copy1.find(
{_id:ObjectId("61517de29946587296c7c375")},

)

.forEach(
 function(item){
  db.knowledge_resource_copy1.update(
  {_id:item._id},
  {$set:{description:item.description.substr(0,4)+"h3"}}
  )
 }
 
);

Comment: Are you sure `db` is well define ? Also, it seem to have an error because there is missing an argument like this: `fun([json}, )`

Comment: this can run ok :System.out.println(MongoUtils.MONGO_TEMPLATE.getDb());

Comment: The js sql also can run ok in navicat

Comment: or is there any way to use mongoTemplate to update data, the js sql like this: db.knowledge_resource_copy1.update(
  {_id:item._id},
  {$set:{description:item.description.substr(0,5)+"h3"}}
  )